# What is the difference between p and P in sed?

Tags: shell, scripting, sed

Can anyone explain what is the difference between `p` and `P` in Sed?

Suppose I want to print lines containing gmail in the below file using both `p` and `P` give the same output:

```
$ cat abc.txt 
Gmail 10
Yahoo 20
Rediff 18

$ sed -n /Gmail/p abc.txt
Gmail 10 

$ sed -n /Gmail/P abc.txt
Gmail 10
```

What is the difference between `p` and `P`?

Answer (score 20):

In [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), `p` prints the addressed line(s), while `P` prints only the first part (up to a newline character `\n`) of the addressed line. If you have only one line in the buffer, `p` and `P` are the same thing, but logically `p` should be used.

Let's look at an academic but easy example. Let's assume we want to print line number 1, we can do

```
$ echo "line 1
$ This is line 2" | sed -n '1p'
> line 1
```

We could also do

```
$ echo "line 1
$ This is line 2" | sed -n '1P'
> line 1
```

Both commands do the same thing, since there is no newline character in the buffer.

But now we use the `N` command to add a second line into the buffer:

```
$ echo "line 1
$ This is line 2" | sed -n '1{N; p}'
> line 1
> This is line 2
```

Now we had 2 lines in the buffer and we print them both with `p`.

```
$ echo "line 1
$ This is line 2" | sed -n '1{N; P}'
> line 1
```

Again we had 2 lines in the buffer, but we printed only the first one, since we were using `P` and not `p`.

Comment: "up to" as in including `\n`?

Answer (score -5):

[Explanation of different option pretty well summarized: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/SedChart.pdf](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/SedChart.pdf)

and for dummy that can read a quick and easy summary in documentatin (like some comment says)

`p` (small) Prints current pattern space

`P` (cap)   Prints first line of current pattern space

so if pattern currently own

```
This first
and second line
```

`p` return

```
This first
and second line
```

`P` return

```
This first
```

Comment: The answer would be waaaay more constructive if You'd pin the exact point not just throw wall of text or some generic off-site manual.

Comment: explaination is full and complete just in answer before (by pfnuesel), this is just the complement and, if somenone cannot read this, it better have to avoid using sed. But ok, i will avoid to give this kind of info.

Comment: Generally, a 'link only' answer is not a good idea, not least because links are seldom as stable as we'd like.  Giving a link as part of an answer which also discusses the point in question is an excellent idea, though.